# how to call a function in flutter from another page

Tags: function, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm new to flutter and i was working on a small poc project. All I Want is that to call a function which is in second page from my first page using abutton click. here what i had done,

1st page

```
class Mainpage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MainpageState createState() => _MainpageState();
}

class _MainpageState extends State<Mainpage> {


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
         backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu,
              color: Colors.grey[500],
            size: 30,),
            onPressed: () {
              print('Click leading');
            },
          ),
        ),
        title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children:<Widget>[
              Text('Basic AppBar'),
            ]
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[

          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.notifications,
            color: Colors.grey[500],
            size: 30,),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/notifications');
            },
          ),
        ],

      ),
      body:
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,10,10,0),

            child: Column(
                children:<Widget>[
       Row(
            children:<Widget>[
      
    ]),
                  SizedBox(height: 60),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children:<Widget>[
                        GestureDetector(
                           child: Image.asset('assets/cam.png',
                               height:90),
                          onTap: () {
                           
                            showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) {
                                return Dialog(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                  elevation: 16,
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 180.0,
                                    width: 330.0,
                                    child: ListView(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                                        //Center(
                                           Padding(
                                             padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:15.0),
                                             child: Text(
                                              "Add a Receipt",

                                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ),
                                           ),
                                       // ),
                                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                                        FlatButton(
                                          child: Text(
                                            'Take a photo..',
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                          ),

                                          onPressed: () {
                                            
                                            });
```

i don't know want to give in the onpressed function at the end of the above code

and the 2nd page is as follow

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();

}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


  File _selectedFile;
  bool _inProcess = false;
  Map data = {};




  Widget getImageWidget() {
    if (_selectedFile != null) {
      return Image.file(
        _selectedFile,
        width: 350,
        height: 650,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      );
    } else {
      return Image.asset(
        "assets/splashlogo.png",
        width: 350,
        height: 650,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      );
    }
  }

  getImage(ImageSource source) async {
    this.setState((){
      _inProcess = true;
    });
    File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    if(image != null){
      File cropped = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
          sourcePath: image.path,
          maxWidth: 1080,
          maxHeight: 1080,

          compressFormat: ImageCompressFormat.jpg,
          androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
              toolbarColor: Colors.black,
              toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
              //toolbarTitle: "RPS Cropper",
              statusBarColor: Colors.deepOrange.shade900,
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
              lockAspectRatio: false
          ),
          iosUiSettings: IOSUiSettings(
            minimumAspectRatio: 1.0,
          )
      );

      this.setState((){
        _selectedFile = cropped;
        _inProcess = false;
      });
    } else {
      this.setState((){
        _inProcess = false;
      });
    }
  
  }
```

i needed to call **getImage(ImageSource.camera);** inside the my onpress function in the 1st page which points to the getimage function on second page.

can anyone help me with it..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here add this in you 1st page in onpressed

```
                                            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context,'/2ndpage',arguments: {
                                              'pickerCode': "0",
                                            });
```

and on the second page you do

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      data = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
      print(data);
      if(data['pickerCode']=="0"){
        getImage(ImageSource.camera);
      }
      
    });
  }
```

this is a tricky thing but I think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a GlobalKey.

```
GlobalKey<_MyHomePageState> globalImageKey = GlobalKey();
```

Change this:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}): super(key:key) 
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();

}
```

when using `MyHomePage`:

```
MyHomePage(key: globalImageKey)
```

call:

```
globalImageKey.currentState.getImage(ImageSource.camera);
```

Comment: can you just show it where to implement in my code,..?